# How to print termination to this program?

Tags: c++

I have a code like this:

```
int main()
{
    int x=0;
    std::cout<<"Enter numbers"<<std::endl;
    while(std::cin>>x)
    {
        std::cout<<"Number entered: "<<x<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I press `ctrl+c` code gets terminated. I would like to print something like 'program terminated because `ctrl+c` was pressed. I know exception handling is a way. But is there any other alternative? By the way, I am running on linux.

Answer (score 1):

No, exception handling has nothing to do with it.

You need to install a signal handler for the `SIGINT` signal using [sigaction(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/sigaction.2.html). Note that signal handling is asynchronous, and most C++ library classes and functions are not reentrant, so your signal handler is fairly limited insofar as what it can do. It can't touch `std::cout`, it can't do much. About the only thing it can do safely is using the [write](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/write.2.html) system call to write a canned message to standard output, before terminating with `_exit()`.

It is possible to use the Linux-specific signal file descriptors to be able to handle signals in a safe manner, permitting the use of the C++ library

Comment: Another useful thing to do in a signal handler is set an [atomic flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag) so that code in the main thread can do something based on the information.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can catch a signal SIGINT (this signal is emited when you press CTRL+C), a little example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
/* procedure signal SIGINT */
static void sigint_handler (int signo)
{
  printf ("signal SIGINT!\n");
  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
int main (void)
{
    if (signal (SIGINT, sigint_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
         fprintf (stderr, "Error in SIGINT!\n");
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (;;)
    pause ( );
    return 0;
}
```